# Is it possible to share worlds in Minecraft for XBox?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

My friend came over and logged into my XBox 360, and we played Minecraft under his account. We created a new world on the local hard drive. But after he left and I logged back into my account (and bought Minecraft), the world we played in together doesn't show up anymore.

Is there any way I can get access to the world created under his account? In general, is there a way to share worlds we create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, its not currently possible to change the ownership of a Minecraft XBLA save game file, at least using legitimate means.

If you put the save game on a USB stick, there are PC applications that can hack the file, but those are officially a violation of the Microsoft XBLA user-level agreement.

Answer (score -1):

I have not tested this with this circumstance but I know that with some other game saves and data that if you go into your game saves on your harddrive and copy it, it will say that it will change the owner to you, which is what you want.